# want to create a semi doughnut shape button clickable in a particular region

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a semi doughnut shaped button which is only clickable in the region where it is visible and not in the the whole rectangular region.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKD45.png

I want clicking to affect only this blue region.

Comment: Can that blue region be a color? or it is going to be an image? just to think of a best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by grabbing the `Bitmap` representation of the `Button`, then testing the x/y pixel's alpha value.

To get the bitmap for a button:

```
Bitmap buttonBmp;
button.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
buttonBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(button.getDrawingCache());
button.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

I'd recommend only doing this once, and saving the results, that way you're not creating a new bitmap every time you touch the button.

Then you override the Button's onTouchEvent so you have the local x/y where the user tapped. If the alpha in that spot is 0, you have a non-clickable area. It's not as simple as an `onClickListener`, but it should do the job.

This way you can use any arbitrary shape, not just a doughnut. Colors, textures, whatever.

Comment: can u explain a little more about it. i have to create a bitmap image ??

Comment: The code I've shown will create a `Bitmap` object from your `Button` object(it's named `button` in the example). Then you check the transparency of whatever pixel you want.

Comment: what's the condition to check the transparency because i haven't work with bitmaps

Comment: Not looking at the docs right now, but I believe it's something like `int alpha = Color.alpha(bitmap.getPixel(x,y));`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure on this but I think this scheme would work. Create an image view in your layout to display the picture and make it clickable via an onTouchEvent. This way you can get the coordinates of the click. Check to make sure that the click is within the inner and outer radii and if it is, do the given response.

Here are a few calculations that will need:

Center of circle
-Assuming the center is the very bottom of the image, this will look something like this(not necessarily exact methods)

```
centerX = img.getX() + img.getWidth()/2;
centerY = img.getY() + img.getHeight()/2;
```

Remember that screen coordinates go from top to bottom and from left to right.

Find the distance away from the center where the click occurred

```
Dx = click.getX() - centerX;
Dy = click.getY() - centerY;
D = Math.sqrt(Dx^2 + Dy^2);
```

Then all you need is to check if the distance is within the radii(not sure how to get the exact radii here, may just need to guess and check. An alternative may be that the top of the semicircle is the top of the picture and then the max height with be the outer radius.)

```
if(D<=outerR && D>=innerR)
    respond();
```

Comment: its a good trick to work with but i have a arc of a circle which center is not on the image. so i cannot find its center. :(
any other suggestions.